# excessive ram usage by pop3-login and imap-login

Tags: memory, dovecot, imap, pop3

I have a VPS with DirectAdmin and Dovecot installed on it. On this server on one of my accounts I have 3 different main account which I've managed using gmail and it's pop3 import feature.
The problem is that the ram usage has gone up from around 300MB to something like 800MB. Through ssh and the 'top' command I can see that there are multiple 'imap-login' and 'pop3-login' instances running on the machine and eating a hell of a lot of memory.
Is there any way to reduce the memory usage by these application?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Dovecot are you running? 
Make sure you're running the latest version which you can install using Directadmin's [Custombuild](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=29824).

Also, you might want to check `/var/log/maillog`, which is where Dovecot usually write its logs, to see if there's anything strange.